Access dirty state of sibling input using Vuelidate
TL;DR Is there a way to correctly access the Vuelidate object from within a validator function?
For context, I'm using Vulidate to validate a form which has inputs for Min Length and Max Length.

Along with the built-in required and between validators, I've written a custom validator to enforce a rule that the min length must be less than or equal to the max length.

This works. However, it can lead to a bad UX interaction where the error can sometimes show in situations where the user is in the middle of typing the max length value. For example, say the user set the min length to 5 and intends to set the max length to 20. In this situation, the error will display when the user types the initial "2" in the max length field.

The ideal situation would be to only display the error once the max length field has been blurred and marked as dirty on the Vuelidate object. But if I add this check by accessing the Vuelidate object within the validator to check the dirty state of the max length field, I get the following error.


I've tried setting the validator to lazy to see if the problem was because the Vuelidate object wasn't available when the component is created, but I still get the error no matter when the validator runs.
The current workaround I'm using is to store a flag as a ref that I set whenever the max length field is blurred and check that flag instead of the $dirty flag on the Vuelidate object, but that feels hacky to me.


The hacky part of your solution is checking the dirty state inside your validator. And it is unnecessary.
Vuelidate has 2 sets of errors: $errors and $silentErrors. $silentErrors contains all failed validations, even in the initial state where the user has not done anything yet and all fields are empty. $errors contains only failed validations from dirty fields. You don't have to check for dirty, because Vuelidate does it for you. All you have to do is to set the dirty state with field.$touch().
